# Scraping a rendered javascript webpage

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping

I'm trying to build a short Python program that extracts Pewdiepie's number of subscribers which is updated every second on socialblade to show it in the terminal. I want this data like every 30 seconds.

I've tried using PyQt but it's slow, i've turned to dryscrape, slightly faster but doesn't work either as I want it to. I've just found Invader and written some short code that still has the same problem : **the number returned is the one before the Javascript on the page is executed** :

```
from invader import Invader

url = 'https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/pewdiepie/realtime'
invader = Invader(url, js=True)

subscribers = invader.take(['#rawCount', 'text'])
print(subscribers.text)
```

I know that this data is accessible via the [site's API](https://bastet.socialblade.com/youtube/lookup?query=UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw) but it's not always working, sometimes it just redirect to [this](https://bastet.socialblade.com/).

Is there a way to get this number after the Javascript on the page modified the counter and not before ? And which method seems the best to you ? Extract it :

- from the original page which always returns the same number for hours ?
- from the API's page which bugs when not using cookies in the code and after a certain amount of time ?

Thanks for your advices !

Answer (score 0):

If you want scrape a web page that has parts of it loaded in by javascript you pretty much need to use a real browser.

In python this can be achieved with `pyppeteer`:

```
import asyncio
from pyppeteer import launch

async def main():
    browser = await launch(headless=False)
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://socialblade.com/youtube/user/pewdiepie/realtime',{
        'waitUntil': 'networkidle0'
    })
    count = int(await page.Jeval('#rawCount', 'e => e.innerText'))
    print(count)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Note: It does not seems like the website you mentioned above is updating the subscriber count frequently any more (even with JavaScript). See: https://socialblade.com/blog/abbreviated-subscriber-counts-on-youtube/

For best success and reliability you will probably need to set the **user agent**(`page.setUserAgent` in `pyppeteer`) and keep it up to date and use **proxies** (so your ip does not get banned). This can be a lot of work.

It might be easier and cheaper (in time and than buying a large pool of proxies) to use a service that will handle this for you like [Scraper's Proxy](https://scrapersproxy.com). It supports will use a real browser and return the resulting html after the JavaScript has run and route all of our requests through a large network of proxies, so you can sent a lot of requests without getting you ip banned.

Here is an example using the Scraper's Proxy API getting the count **directly from YouTube**:

```
import requests
from pyquery import PyQuery

# Send request to API
url = "https://scrapers-proxy2.p.rapidapi.com/javascript"

params = {
    "click_selector": '#subscriber-count', # (Wait for selector work-around)
    "wait_ajax": 'true',
    "url":"https://www.youtube.com/user/PewDiePie"
}

headers = {
    'x-rapidapi-host': "scrapers-proxy2.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "<INSERT YOUR KEY HERE>" # TODO
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=params)

# Query html
pq = PyQuery(response.text)
count_text = pq('#subscriber-count').text()

# Extract count from text
clean_count_text = count_text.split(' ')[0]
clean_count_text = clean_count_text.replace('K','000')
clean_count_text = clean_count_text.replace('M','000000')
count = int(clean_count_text)

print(count)
```

I know this is a bit late, but I hope this helps